# Custom UI in Auth0 Vue

Tags: vue.js, auth0

## problem

Is there a way to make a custom UI in Auth0 Vue? I tried to do this for forever now but I can't find a way to do it using the Auth0 Vue SDK. There was a way to do it with WebAuth: `auth0.client.login` but after hours of searching I could not find a way to do it with Vue.

Comment: For custom UI you are talking about the login page right?

Comment: @HenryPeregrino Yes, I found a way to add a custom UI for signing up, but not for logging in apparently :[